# onPostExecute() method not being executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 web service methods being called in AsyncTask. The first one is being successfully called but the second web service method is not called. Any idea how to call the second method after the first?

AsyncTask code

```
public class Transaction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        private String finalBalance1 = "", price1 = "", pName = "", pNric = "", pClass = "", sno = "";
        public Transaction(String price1, String pName, String pNric, String pClass, String sno, String finalBalance1)
        {
            super();
            this.finalBalance1 = Double.toString(finalBalance);
            this.price1 = Double.toString(sPrice);
            this.pName = sRA.studentName;
            this.pNric = sRA.studentNric;
            this.pClass = sRA.studentClass;
            this.sno = logger.stallNo;
        }
        @Override
          protected String doInBackground (String...url)
          { 
            String result = "";

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://152.226.152.175/NCO/WebService.asmx/InsertStudentTransaction");
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NRIC", pNric));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", pName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Class", pClass));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StallNo", sno));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AmountSpent", price1));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result = line;
                }

             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
              }

        protected void onPostExecute (String result)
          {
            if(result != null)
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://152.226.152.175/NCO/WebService.asmx/UpdateParticulars");
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NRIC", pNric));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FixedAmount", finalBalance1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", pName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Class", pClass));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }


             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Transaction.execute();` ?

Comment: I've already done it under my button's onclicklistener

Comment: you should make second AsynkTask and call it from onPost of first one.

Comment: Stacks28 - I've added it,but there is a networkonmainthreadexception now

Comment: That is becuase onPostExecute is on the main thread.  That is why you should create a second Async Task

Comment: but why are you two times post data to server??

Comment: Shani Goriwal - I am doing updating of data on one database and inserting of record into another database. Both database are in a server

Comment: if you have network thread problem then you have to use strict mode.

Comment: ObieMD5 - Thanks, I managed to solve it by adding another asynctask. Is it possible to do it in the onPostExecute() method?

Comment: @山本一樹 yes you can create another async task from within another async task however, you can only do it from the main thread functions such as `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override is missing before onPostExecute(String result), and check result getting null
```

Comment: I've added it,but there is a networkonmainthreadexception now

Comment: make sure you have to write Intermet permission in manifest file

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

> Create a instance of AsyncTask and then do it finally.and also override method is missing.

```
instance.execute();
```

> and add

```
@override before the post execute method.
```

Comment: What does this have to do with anything?  The instance is already been executed hence why doInBackground is running and onPostExecute will run automatically if it is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Override to the onPostExecute method and also you can not use the network transmission on the main thread.  The stuff that is within the onPostExecute needs to be done within another AsyncTask.

From [Android Dev Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask):

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this
>   from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations
>   on a separate thread from the UI. The AsyncTask class provides one of
>   the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

@override

protected void onPostExecute (String result){

Log.i("AsynckTask",result);

}

if you want consult another webservice you need other AsynkTask remember the connection made in background not in UIThread

@override

protected void onPostExecute (String result){

Log.i("AsynckTask",result);

//made new connection

new AsynkTas().execute();

}